# Call a method object with arguments that returns variable

Tags: excel, vba, object, methods, parameter-passing

How can I call a method passing multiple parameters returning a variable?

I have a class called **cExcelTable**. Inside I have a method:

```vb
Public Function GetColumnNumberByColumnName(strColumnName As String)
    Dim resultColumnFound As Integer

    '... Here i have the code which find the right column
    '... then i return the result as an integer

    GetColumnNumberByColumnName = resutColumnFound
End Function
```

How can I call this method and get the returning value?

I want the equivalent of this:

```vb
Dim myTable As New cExcelTable
    
Dim i as Integer
        
myTable.Workbook = "file.xlsx"
myTable.Sheet = "TestingSheet"
myTable.Table = "TabDatas"
'... And here is my bug that i don't know how to solve
i = myTable.GetColumnNumberByColumnName("TOTAL")
```

I know that for a method not have returning values I must use **Call** but what about a method that return a value?

Comment: That looks like it should work. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Try setting the return value of the function as an integer:  `Public Function GetColumnNumberByColumnName(strColumnName As String) As Integer` and see if that helps.

Comment: The name of the variable in GetColumnNumberByColumnName used to return a value is spelled incorrectly.  It should be `GetColumnNumberByColumnName = resultColumnFound`.

Comment: FWIW you do not _have_ to use Call.  If fact you should not use it, s it's obsolete

Comment: If you use Option Explicit you would have caught this error

Comment: Hello, in fact everybody help me. It was the night i was tired and thanks to PeterT and Domenic i found that i have misspelled the return value but also another value inside my method. As Neil B was asking this was  "Error number 9 : the index do not belong to the selection" So sorry for waisting a little bit of your time and many thanks :) it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Thanks to *PeterT* and *Domenic* in comments i found after a night sleep that my mistake was not the calling of the method but misspelled of two variables inside my method and adding the type it should return

So for a new one who go inside this post the answer is
Inside the method you should use this

```
'Add the type the method it should return "As Integer"
Public Function nameOfTheMethod(parameterNumber1 As String) As Integer
    Dim resultColumnFound As Integer

    '... type your code
    '... then return the result with the correct spelling

    GetColumnNumberByColumnName = resultColumnFound
End Function
```

And then inside your code you can call your method like this

```
Dim myObject As New cMyClass 'cMyClass  is the name of your class and myObject is the name of your object you are creating
Dim i as Integer

i = myObject.nameOfTheMethod("test")
```